# read a list of values from another table using subquery and check where in condition

Tags: mysql, sql

A small question may be it is silly but I am not getting idea how to solve this problem

```
select * from customers where id in(select assigned from users where username='test');
```

in the above query

```
select assigned from users where username='test'
```

this returns 1,2

but the condition where in doesnot work which should be like below

```
select * from customers where id in(1,2);
```

this is not the exact output i am just guessing that it might be this way. which is not so the problem is occuring.

i am getting only one row that is corresponding to 1

so help me figuring this out.

please check the sqlfiddle below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95c28/2

thanks

Comment: assigned column contains comma seperated values

Comment: As in... a string "1,2"?

Comment: thats what how to split

Comment: We need to know about schema of your tables. It's kinda strange to having two entries in users table whose username is 'test' and the value of their `assigned` is different! That's a strange design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM customers c
JOIN users u ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id, u.assigned) IS NOT NULL
```

Putting comma-separated values is a bad idea in relational databases, it makes everything more complicated. You should use a relation table instead, so you can write a normal equality join. The above query cannot be indexed, so it will be very innefficient if the tables are large.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/668e6/1)

Comment: yeah its a bad idea but for now I wanna do that way..check my question again I have updated it with a screenshot. see if you can figure out some way

Comment: My answer IS the way.

Comment: Please post plain text so it's easier to copy and paste into test tables. Best is to create a page at sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Updated answer to suppress duplicates with `DISTINCT c.*`, and added fiddle

Answer (score 0):

if `select assigned from users where username='test'` returns 1,2. This means your customer table contains only Id=1.

Comment: I added an sqlfiddle please check it or suggest better way seeing the tables